# jQuery add and remove delay

Tags: jquery, delay

how a can get this, in jQuery: call some function with working code after delay(3s), IF i call function again before delay from first call in not done, then reset delay and call new 3s.

Example:

fce MeDeday(3s) - after time down - alert("hello");

**situation 1:**

call MeDelay() - time down - alert("hello")

**situation 2:**

call MeDelay()

still remain 2s from first call

reset time and again wait 3s, no 2s + 5s and fired 2times alert("hello")

call MeDelay() - time down - alert("hello")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **debouncing,** which is closely related to **throttling.** There's a nice jQuery plugin for that: [jQuery throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

I think this is the use case you're looking for:

```
function fn()
{
    alert('hello');
}

var debouncedFn = $.debounce(3000, fn);

$('#my-button').click(debouncedFn);
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/DDy5u/)***

Comment: I have one preblem a i want to work like this EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/DDy5u/3/

Comment: @JinDave: `$.debounce()` returns a function. You need to execute that function, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/J8zrD/1/).

Answer (score 4):

Without jQuery:

```
var MeDelay = (function() {
    var timer;
    return function(timeout) {
        timeout = timeout || 3000;
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('hello');
        }, timeout);
    }
}());
```