# OnChange event fires too soon in dropdown / select input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I feel stupid even putting this question out here, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Maybe this is how the onchange event is supposed to work, but it seems like it is firing too soon (or that it should fire again when the final selection is made). I have a select / dropdown that I use to refresh part of my screen, but I've found that in Chrome and IE9 it the onchange event is called as soon as the user starts **typing** (works fine with a mouse selection) - I suppose this makes sense because a new selection is made even if they aren't done typing. Anyway, the screen updates, but not with the data for the user's final selection in the dropdown (it's like it fires on the first hit/change, but it doesn't fire again when the user stops typing and a final selection is made).

I've switched it to onblur but then it isn't fired until the user is done selecting and moves on, so I'd love to find a solution that fires sooner than onblur, but after the user's final selection is made.

This is on an aspx page in an MVC progject:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="employeeDropdown" runat="server" onchange="RefreshCalendarData()" />
```

This is the js function its calling:

```
function RefreshCalendarData() {
    // code omitted
    Scheduler.Refresh();
}
```

Are there any good solutions/workarounds using js or jQuery?

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET _use_ jQuery? Also, I don't see this problem (at least in Chrome) where the `change` event does not fire for the user's final dropdown selection: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Mx7TN/

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - I did try this with jquery as well. I still experienced the issue. You seem correct as I was unable to repeat the problem with your example, but my list contains about 150 items - but I agree, that shouldn't matter and it seems like it should fire once the final selection is made - and maybe it is firing a second time, but my refresh process takes long enough that it isn't being called again (or it is still executing so the call gets ignored)? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Probably the best approach is not to use onchange for select menus, and to have a small 'Go' button next to the select. IE will also trigger onchange for any select navigation using the arrow keys, which could be any user who isn't using the mouse

Comment: Hmmm. If `Scheduler.Refresh()` takes a long time to execute, you should think about [debouncing the call](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/). I'm not sure if ASP.NET has anything built-in, but if not, that plugin will do the trick.

Comment: Logging does show that the final selection is being called, the refresh process isn't being run a second time if it is already running though.

Comment: Debouncing was the answer. I ended up solving with a non-plugin solution similar to what @MДΓΓБДLL suggested. This question was essentially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340053/jquery-add-and-remove-delay I just didn't know the question I needed to ask.

Comment: Funny, that's one of my answers `:P`

Answer (score 1):

You can use server controls in an ASP.NET MVC project (with very few exceptions).  DDL's work correctly in IE/Chrome when typing - see and [My blog Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)
Play around with my Cascading DDL sample.

Comment: This might have helped, but this page had to remain an aspx page, due to a 3rd party control we needed. The project is MVC, but not this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes the onChange event is working as it should. what you can do is attach a timer to the window and check if the field has been modified instead of using onChange.

so you could create a global var that updates to true when the user blurs the form and a timer to check if the user has made a last selection.

```
if(userBlur == true && userSelect == true){
    //do the code
    window.clearInterval();
}else{
    //wait for change
}
```

should be closer to what you are expecting.

Comment: No, polling with timer is not remotely necessary here.